# Why the background of <span> behaves differently when the content contains new lines?

Tags: css, html

To demonstrate the behaviour with some visual feedback we have the following style for the `span`:

```
span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

If we write something like this, then the result looks OK and both spans have red background with a space in between:

```
<span>Hello</span>
<span>World</span>
```

But when we change the HTML to something like this, then there is no space between the two spans:

```
<span>
  Hello
</span>
<span>
  World
</span>
```

I would assume that the spaces and new lines wouldn't affect anything. So my question is why is that happening and what am I missing here?

Here is a screenshot of the first and second behaviour in action (tested on Chrome, Safari, Firefox):

[image]

[jsbin.com/eGElekoW](http://jsbin.com/eGElekoW/2/edit)

Comment: Hey bud, that second one literally contains all of the spacing that is between the two words whereas the first one just contains the words and HTML puts in its own actual space. It's just adding that space on the second line that is allowing for HTML to interpret it as everything should be red. It may not work in all browsers though. In other words, the browsers are interpreting the spaces  that the HTML code sends through to it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/7wsfJ/ . My example shows that the browser is interpreting the spaces after the "hello" section but it doesn't matter about the "world" section because the span starts at the "w". If that makes sense, I can put it up as an answer and then go into a bit more detail about it.

Comment: Yes and actually I played with all of the different combinations. My problem was that I wanted to have the first result with the second approach (to break lines) for some automated code and to avoid to having long lines. Most likely will end up putting the contents in the same (long line).. but either case I still think that it should have the space in between in the second case as well.. cause the total width in both cases is the same..

Comment: If you just make sure that the line break happens outside of a span tag you can still avoid long lines, just don't include any breaks or whitespace inside of a span tag.

Comment: Just use a <p> tag and put all of the spans inside of it to put them on the same line.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast There are millions of different ways of solving the actual problem.. thank you very nice, but I think my question is very specific and I wanted to learn why is that happening and not how to solve the visual stuff...

Comment: @chiliNUT That's what I ended up doing, but it still feels to me that it should be the same :)

Comment: Hey dude check out the edit to my answer. I don't know if your particular situation requires you to use `display:inline` strictly, but using `inline-block` will allow both forms of your HTML to display how you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: For addressing the particular issue which inspired this question, using a style of

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

will allow both forms of your HTML to yield the white sliver in between the 2 red blocks, since now the spans have block spacing and sizing while still adhering to an inline positioning. Anyway, onto the explanation:

Newline or a space are both a single white space. If 2 inline elements have a single space between them, you get that little sliver of white space.

```
<span>Hello</span>
<span>World</span>
```

has a single space (the newline) between the 2 span elements. It is equiavelent to this

```
<span>Hello</span> <span>World</span>
```

However,

```
<span>Hello </span>
<span>World</span>
```

has no space between the span elements, because its HTML so any amount of contiguous white space is considered a single whitespace. this time, the first whitespace is inside of the span, so it gets a red background, the second white space (the newline) gets bunched up with the first one, which has a red background already, so no white sliver is seen. The above block is equivalent to your

```
<span>
  Hello
</span>
<span>
  World
</span>
```

because the whitespace after the "o" is inside the span, so that gets bunched up with the newline whitespace outside the span, as well as the newline whitespace inside the second span before the W, so the background is contiguous.

You can see that

```
<span>Hello</span><span>World</span>
```

would have a contiguous red background also, but with no visible spacing between the words.

Comment: That looks legit.. but still weird why they decided to not have the visual space and instead having the continuous red background when that happens: `<span>Hello </span> <span>World</span>`. At least they are consistent in different browsers :)

Comment: It appears that the "rule" being observed is that the "first" whitespace takes precedence, and the rest are ignored. In your particular situation I agree that the sliver of white makes more sense, but as an overarching general rule, observing the first whitespace and ignoring all subsequent contiguous whitespace makes sense to me. What I would consider WEIRD FOR SURE is that the tags are ignored in this calculation, letting the whitespace "run thru" the `</span>` tag.

Comment: Indeed with the `inline-block` the result is the one that I would expect. But the more I think about it, the more it make sense what they decided to do with the default behaviour. Because `span` shouldn't provide any visual change by itself and with the combination of the fact that only the first space is the important one, I think it explains it.. :)

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#white-space-processing for detailed white space collapsing rules.